# Excel 2013 VBA: Error -2147417848 Method 'Select' of object 'Range' failed

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting the above error in my Excel code below.  This code is for re-arranging the row height of rows with merged cells.  The code was copied directly from microsoft's support site and works fine if used only once.

In my loop below, it infact works perfectly fine on the 1st six merged cells.

The error only occurs on the line:

```
NewWorksheet.Range(NewWorksheet.Cells(RowCounter, 5), NewWorksheet.Cells(RowCounter, 6)).Select
```

while executing 24th iteration of the 'For' loop.  Value of ErrorFile_LastRow is 43.  The 1st merged cell is at row 18.  Row 24 has un-merged cells.  I had found a somewhat relevant article from microsoft at  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/319832 and as such added the oXL references in the code below.  Based that same article, I added the NewWorksheet in the offending lines, but none of that has helped.

The same error occurs at exact same line on the exact same iteration regradless of any of the above changes or what and how many applications are running.  I have even tried to restart my laptop and make sure that only the macro is running an no other office application, but even that does not seem to help.

Infact, if someone can tell me how to do adjust row height of the merged cells without using 'Select', 'ActiveCell', etc. that would be the best as I am trying not to use these kinds of commands so as to both increase the robustness & speed of the code and also to make sure that macro does not stop processing just becuase I am working on another application.

Relevent code snippet (the macro itself is highly complex):-

```
Dim oXL As Excel.Application
Dim NewWorkbook As Workbook
Dim NewWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim ErrorFile_LastRow As Long
Dim MergedHeight As Single
Dim MergedWidth As Single
Dim PossNewRowHeight As Single
Dim lngRowCount As Long
Dim lngColCount As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim RowCounter As Long
Dim ActiveCellWidth As Single

Set oXL = Excel.Application

    oXL.Workbooks.Add
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    '   Create a workbook handle for the new workbook
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Set NewWorkbook = oXL.ActiveWorkbook
    '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    '   Use the new workbook handle.
    '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    With NewWorkbook
        '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        '   Create a new worksheet handle for the new workbook.
        '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Set NewWorksheet = .Sheets(1)
    End With

    '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    '   Use the new worksheet handle.
    '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    With NewWorksheet
        '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        '   Capture the last row of data to process.
        '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ErrorFile_LastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row
        .Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(ErrorFile_LastRow, 6)).Select
    End With

    NewWorksheet.Activate
    Application.PrintCommunication = True
    NewWorksheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = Selection.Address
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    '   Adjust the row height to fit the data.
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    For RowCounter = 2 To ErrorFile_LastRow
        If RowCounter <> ErrorFile_LastRow Then
            NewWorksheet.Range(NewWorksheet.Cells(RowCounter, 5), NewWorksheet.Cells(RowCounter, 6)).Select
        Else
            NewWorksheet.Range(Cells(RowCounter, 1), Cells(RowCounter, 6)).Select
        End If
        If ActiveCell.MergeCells Then
            With ActiveCell.MergeArea
                If .WrapText = True Then
                    lngRowCount = .Rows.Count
                    lngColCount = .Columns.Count
                    MergedHeight = Selection.Height
                    For i = 1 To lngColCount
                        MergedWidth = .Cells(1, i).ColumnWidth + 1 + MergedWidth
                    Next i
                    If MergedHeight > 409.5 Then
                        MergedHeight = 409.5
                    End If
                    If MergedWidth > 409.5 Then
                        MergedHeight = 409.5
                    End If
                    ActiveCellWidth = ActiveCell.ColumnWidth
                    .MergeCells = False
                    .Cells(1).RowHeight = MergedHeight
                    .Cells(1).ColumnWidth = MergedWidth
                    .EntireRow.AutoFit
                    PossNewRowHeight = .Cells(1).RowHeight
                    .MergeCells = True
                    .Cells(1).ColumnWidth = ActiveCellWidth
                    For i = 1 To lngRowCount
                        .Cells(i, 1).RowHeight = PossNewRowHeight / lngRowCount
                    Next i
                End If
            End With
        End If
    Next RowCounter
```

Comment: I see no obvious reason for that particular line of code to fail. The error you are getting is nearly always related to trying to `Select` cells from a `Worksheet` that is not the `ActiveSheet`.  Add a line before the error line to verify that you are indeed on the right sheet: `Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Name = NewWorksheet.Name`.  Since this is a "complex macro" do you have any `Worksheet_Change` or `Worksheet_SelectionChange` events in place?  Those might wreak havoc with all of the selecting going on.

Answer (score 0):

make sue **ErrorFile_LastRow**  is initialized somewhere.

Comment: Sorry I missed copying that code here.  I added it to the snippet above.  Value of ErrorFile_LastRow is 43.